# Need Help in java android application

Tags: java, android, for-loop, project

I am trying to generate 5 letters word from random letters. Everything works fine but when I click my button to generate words it takes near about 2 minutes to generate those words and for those 2 minutes my button remains tapped(In blue color), which doesn't look good. I thought to put processing ring but that also doesn't work. Below is some coding for my method

```
String finalWrd = searchWrd.toUpperCase();
        String twoLetterString = "";
        int wordLen = searchWrd.length();//searchWrd is a random letter entered by user
        String[] array = finalWrd.split("");    
        for(int i =1; i<=wordLen; i++)
            for(int j=1; j<=wordLen; j++)
                for(int K=1; K<=wordLen; K++)
                    for(int l=1; l<=wordLen; l++){
                        for(int m=1; m<=wordLen; m++){
                            twoLetterString += array[i] + array[j]+ array[K]+ array[l] + array[m] +",";
                        }

                    }

String[] array2Letters = twoLetterString.split(",");




    int a =array2Letters.length, b = dictLinesArray.length;

    for(int i =0;i<a; i++)
    { 

        for(int l=0;l<b;l++)
        {
            if(array2Letters[i].equals(dictLinesArray[l]))
            {
                dictString2Lettes += dictLinesArray[l] +"," ;
            } 
        }
    }


    text = dictString2Lettes;
```

Please help me, I need it for my college project. Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for atleast you have tried your self, good

Comment: Sooo many for loops. Thats your problem right there.

Comment: Why are there so many loops?  What are you accomplishing with that?

Comment: Two or three suggestions.
1. Try to use some Math libraries to generate all permutations of a 5 character string. Could be faster than writing your own code.
2. Use a spinner while computing the result?

Comment: @Sanchit and @ Makoto 
What I am doing is rearranging postions of  the letters which I got from user and then comparing each word with a dictionary file and then saving the matching words into a string. Everything works fine, but it is taking too long to do processing.

Comment: What is dictLinesArray? You can change the data structure to use list or set or map and call `contains` instead of looping to see a match.

Comment: @smk Thanks for your help, can you please tell me something more about your 2 ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is dictLinesArray filled with 5 letter words?

Comment: @baraky dictLinesArray is an array which contains all the dictionary word from a file

Comment: @Sanchit no it is dictLinesArray contains all the dictinary letters

Comment: so if orange is in the dictionary. and I type in orange. what does it find? Nothing by your codes logic.

Comment: @Sanchit no it will find orange 
for e.g. I put "ingus" it is able to find "using" successfully

Comment: That's a 5 letter word. Orange is a 6 letter word. Your dictionay contains `orange` you are only checking for 5 letter words in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to offer you a decent solution to improve the performance of your algorithm.  Use @Seraphim 's (or similar) answers to improve your user friendliness.

**Fix your dictionary data structure.**

1) Make your dictionary a `Map<String,ArrayList<String>>`.

2) Add words in your dictionary like such:

```
String[] oldDictionary = {"using","suing","apple","orange"};
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < oldDictionary.length; i++) {
  char[] sort = oldDictionary[i].toCharArray();
  Arrays.sort(sort);
  String alphabetical = new String(sort);
  if (map.containsKey(alphabetical)) {
    map.get(alphabetical).add(oldDictionary[i]);
  } else {
    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add(oldDictionary[i]);
    map.put(alphabetical, tmp);
  }
}
```

You can now use this new and improved data structure to find words super easily.

```
String inputWord = "iusgn";
char[] sort = inputWord.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(sort);
inputWord = new String(sort);

if (map.containsKey(inputWord)) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String word : map.get(inputWord)) {
    sb.append(word + ",");
  }
  sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
} else {
  System.out.println("Nothing found :(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll not comment the inefficency of your algorithm (try to find something better! :)). **I'll simply give a solution for the UI that looks freezed:**

*"my button remains tapped(In blue color), which doesn't look good"*

When your computation need time to be done, you need something like **AsyncTask**:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Suppose you are in your activity named MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //execute async task
            new FindWordsTask().execute();              
        }
    });
}
```

Than you set up you **AsyncTask** like that:

```
private class FindWordsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,
                "Title",
                "Finding words...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //do the computation,
        //use here your function

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the inefficiency in his code. It'll be a lot more user friendly though.

Comment: The problem arisen with the question is that the UI looks freezed! Keeping the MainThread away long from computation is always very important.

Comment: I agree! I'm all for user friendliness although an inefficient algorithm will make him wait at the "Finding words..." screen for far too long. What if I input `Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis` That program is goign to be running for a good couple of years.

Comment: Check out my answer for some more power :) With our powers combined we can solve this guys problem!

Comment: I hope this combination will be understood!

Answer (score 0):

I guess what takes you the most time is the second loop (because `dictLinesArray` is big)

Try to change `dictLinesArray` to Set and use `contains`. The `dictLinesSet` initialization should be done only once (at some init function).

```
Set<String> dictLinesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(dictLinesArray));


for(int i =0;i<a; i++){
    if (dictLinesSet.contains(array2Letters[i])){
         dictString2Lettes += array2Letters[i] +"," ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not supporting dictLinesArray.contains

Comment: Yes you need to change it to Set.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts, I hope they help.

In your construction you are actually doing some less-than-optimal data management. Since the strings are immutable, for each time you go through the inner most loop (which is wordLen^5 iterations) you are creating 6 total String objects (right of the = sign), and making a seventh (left of the = sign). Strings are immutable in Java, and memory is a bigger concern in mobile apps than in laptop/desktop development. So for a word length of 5 you are creating 21,875 Objects. For a wordLen of 8 you are creating 229,376 Objects, and it only gets worse.

Better is to use a StringBuilder and store the value after you're done:

You would also want to make the twoLetterString a string builder from the get go.

```
StringBuilder twoLetterStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
//inside the loop
    twoLetterStringBuilder.append(array[i]).append(array[j]). ... .append(",");
```

At the end, just use

```
twoLetterStringBuilder.toString().split(",");
```

AsyncTask will keep things from locking up, but this should help you be much more efficient with your creation of objects and overall processing time.

Is the reason for all of the for loops some necessity to have an array of all possible permutations? If not just use:

```
Random r = new Random();
int arrayIndex = r.nextInt(wordLen);
```